# Xcode workspace builds but not project

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, cocoapods, aws-amplify

I am able to successfully build my project in the workspace (.xcworkspace), but when I open the project (xcodeproj) and try to build it there I get errors. A screenshot of the errors is attached. I've tried updating pods, installing, etc, but still cannot manage to get past this. Any advice?

edit:
This project/workspace is cloned from a repo. Whenever I clone to a new folder, I update pods.

After that, I am able to run the workspace, but not the project.

This repo is used by other people but they do not run into the same issue as me, they are able to run the project. This leads me to believe this has to do something with my Xcode setup. I have tried reinstalling and whatnot but still no success.

[image]

Comment: I assume you created workspace as result of using Cocoapods? If so, you simply don’t open the xcodeproj anymore. Always use xcworkspace.

Comment: I'm not sure.. How would I fix that. I added more detail into the post. Thanks!

Comment: There’s nothing to “fix”. You reference having “pods” (i.e., that your project is using Cocoapods). That means that Cocoapods was used to create the  `xcworkspace`, and you simply never open the `xcodeproj` again. Use the `xcworkspace` only from this point on. If your teammates are saying that they’re opening “the project”, they’re using that term generally, likely not specifically referring to the `xcodeproj`. They are undoubtedly opening `xcworkspace`, just like you should.

Comment: As the [Cocoapods site](https://cocoapods.org/) says under the “Getting started” tab, “Make sure to always open the Xcode workspace instead of the project file when building your project.”

Comment: @Rob I came here to comment the exact same thing :D  It was discussed in Dr. Angela's iOS and Swift course, which I recently finished.  Good observation about OP's teammates' use of 'project' being generic:  that part had me second-guessing whether there could actually be a problem with Xcode.

Comment: BTW, if you are in the command line and want to open a project, it is `xed .`, which will open the workspace if present, and if not, will open the `.xcodeproj`.